# import tensorflow error for ubuntu 16.04 "ImportError: No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal"

Tags: tensorflow

I am not able to call tensorflow getting the below error

```
    (TF) drx@drx:~$ python
    Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import tensorflow
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
    File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
      raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    ImportError: No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal

    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

My CUDA version is

```
    (TF) drx@drx:~$ nvcc --version
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
    Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61`
```

My cuDNN version is

```
    #define CUDNN_MAJOR      5
    #define CUDNN_MINOR      1
    #define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 10
```

Could someone guide me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved. The tensorflow was trying to import packages from a different location. I have uninstalled tensorflow by command then deleted all folders with name tensorflow and reinstall a fresh version. Now it's working fine.